# How to use W3C Email Regex in Elixir

Tags: regex, elixir

I'm trying to use the following W3C Email Regex in Elixir (source: [RegexPal](https://www.regexpal.com/97767)):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

In a function that looks like this

```elixir
def get_type(value) do
    cond do
        String.match?(value, ~r/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/) ->
            :email

        String.match?(value, ~r/^\+[1-9][0-9]\d{1,14}$/) ->
            :phone_number
    end
end
```

But I'm getting a compilation error

```
unexpected token: "`" (column 56, code point U+0060)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you used `/` to delimit the content of your sigil, you need to escape the `/` character in your regexp. An other solution is to choose a delimiter that is not part of the regexp (like `'` or `<` for example) to avoid the need of escaping.

```
~R/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
# or
~R<^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not particularly answering your question regarding regex, which was perfectly answered by @julp.

I am here to tell **do not use regex to validate emails**. The regular expression you’ve mentioned is not nearly correct by any means.

Here is an example of a perfectly valid email that won’t pass your regex: `"John Smith"@example.com`.

[More](https://gist.github.com/cjaoude/fd9910626629b53c4d25).

So my guess would be: check if there is `@` or not.

```rb
def get_type(value) do
  if String.contains?(value, "@"),
      do: :email,
    else: :phone_number
end
```

Comment: This makes A LOT OF sense. For a while I was thinking "well but what if I get the john@doe as input, it would be wrong" but this situation would actually never happen, since the validation happens in another place from a third part. This function really should just tell if an input is email or a phone number. Thanks for this clever tip

Comment: `john@doe` is a perfectly valid email though, according to RFC2822, RFC5322, and RFC6854.

Answer (score 1):

One very practical way of avoiding this problem is to simply write the regex as a string and call Regex.compile! on it.

```
Regex.compile!("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$")
```